# Saving Camera Intent Image To Internal Data Custom Directory

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

**My Problem**

I have a camera intent which I want the image to be saved to a directory in my internal data directory.

I have created the directory using:

```
        File mydir3 = new File(this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),File.separator+"MyApplication"+File.separator+CCPhotoManager.DIRECTORY+File.separator+PhotoManager);
        mydir3.mkdirs();
```

I then proceed to create the file with the specified name as you can see below.

```
       String filePath = this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+File.separator+"MyApplication"+File.separator+PhotoManager+File.separator+PhotoManager().getNewPhotoFileName()+PhotoManager;

        File file = new File(filePath);
```

Then I read somewhere that the reason the image isn't being saved is because the camera doesn't have permission to access my applications data directory and that you need to use `FileOutputStream` to change the permission. However, due to my file's path having path separators I couldn't use `openFileStream(filePath,Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE);`.

This is why I tried the below.

```
       try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However this obviously doesn't work because no image is saved to the file created using the code below.

```
        Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(file);
        Log.d("PhotoManager", "adding extra to intent: "+uriSavedImage.toString());
        Intent launchcameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        launchcameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
        startActivityForResult(launchcameraIntent,CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

**My Question**

How do I get a camera intent to save its image to my custom directory in my internal data?

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I solved it. Thanks goes to @AppMobiGurmeet also.

Save the photo to a file on the SDCard like below.

```
        File directory= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyApplication"+File.separator+"TemporaryImages");//+File.separator+CCPhotoManager.getInstance().getNewPhotoFileName()+CCPhotoManager.JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX);
        directory.mkdirs();

        File externalFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyApplication"+File.separator+"TemporaryImages"+File.separator+CCPhotoManager.getInstance().getNewPhotoFileName()+CCPhotoManager.JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX);

        Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(externalFile);
        Log.d("PhotoManager", "adding extra to intent: "+uriSavedImage.toString());
        Intent launchcameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        launchcameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
        startActivityForResult(launchcameraIntent,CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Then on activity result. (when the intent is returned)

```
            // SAVE THE PHOTO TO THE INTERNAL DATA DIRECTORY
            File to = new File(MyApplication.getAppContext().getFilesDir()+File.separator+"MyApplication"+File.separator+DIRECTORY+File.separator+this._currentPhotoName+JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX);
            File from = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyApplication"+File.separator+"TemporaryImages"+File.separator+this._currentPhotoName+JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX);

            try {
                FileChannel destination = new FileOutputStream(to).getChannel();
                FileChannel source = new FileInputStream(from).getChannel();
                if (destination != null && source != null) {
                    destination.transferFrom(source,0,source.size());
                    from.delete();
                }
                destination.close();
                source.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I have now decided however, after all this faffing around, that the internal data directory is not the best place to store things like Images and Files due to, on some devices, there being a very small amount of internal space (Samsung Galaxy Ace approx 200MB).

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem once and I solved it with this:

1.Create a file from a image that exists in a default folder as:

```
File from = new File("path to default file created");
```

Here in your code path is described as filepath.

2.Create another File where you want the file to save as:

```
File to = new File("target file path");
```

3.Rename the file as:

```
from.renameTo(to);
```

With this the file from default path is automatically deleted and created at the new path.

thanks

Comment: So add the from file as the file for the camera intent to save to. Then on the intent received (after the picture is taken) rename the file to the one in my internal data directory?\

Comment: The rename function on the from file is not working. I do a log after the rename and it the path is still the same as before?